# How do i parse a string in python and write it as an xml to a new xml file?

Tags: python, xml

I have xml data in string format which is in variable xml_data

```
xml_data="<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>"
```

I want to save this data to a new xml file through python.

I am using this code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.XML(xml_data)
```

Now Here i want to create a xml file and save the xml tree to the file, but don't know which function to use for this.

Thanks

Comment: If you just want to write it to a file, why are you parsing it in the first place?  Why not simply `open("file", "w").write(xml_data)`?

Comment: U caught me red-handed.......THANKS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With `ET.tostring(tree)` you get a non-formatted string representation of the XML. To save it to a file:

```
with open("filename", "w") as f:
    f.write(ET.tostring(tree))
```

Comment: maybe is better to write this as: `with open("filename.xml", "wb") as f: f.write(ET.tostring(tree))`

Answer (score 6):

In python 3.x
The proposed solution won't work unless you specify `with open("filename", "wb") as f:` instead of `with open("filename", "w") as f:`